# For loop doesn't work in array (Javascript, Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array that contains cameras specifications, the problem occurs when I try to run a for loop to get the elements.

Here is the content of my array :

[image]

I tried all different types of for loops like forEach, basic for loop with increment or for (`let item of myArray`)

For loop doesn't run and I have no return of the element in  the array.

```
for (let id in elements) {

      if (typeof elements[id].brands !== 'undefined') {

        delete this.items;

        let itemsArray = [];

        for (let elementData of elements[id].brands) {

          this.http.get("assets/data/" + elementData + "Reflex.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

            Array.prototype.push.apply(itemsArray, data);

          });

        }

        this.items = itemsArray;

      }

      if (typeof elements[id].sensorSize !== 'undefined') {


      }

    }
```

(`this.items` is the array that you can see on the top (I use Angular2)).

Comment: You are probably getting `this.items` through an http call and it's undefined by the time your code reaches to the loop.

Comment: Have you tried the most basic loop? for (let i=0; i<this.items.length; i++) { } for example?

Comment: can you add the code where you are running the for loop?

Comment: i don't get this.items through an http call :/ @echonax

Comment: Add a console log for `this.items.length`.

Comment: @torazaburo this output me a 0 so for him the length of the array is 0

Comment: @rrd yes i tried it but the items.length seems to be 0

Comment: You should post your entire script, I don't think the problem comes from the for loop (or we should all stop working with JS and go on strike...), but from the items list that is not filled with values.

Comment: Problem is in your `this` most likely. Please use `console.log(this)` and tell us if it references the proper object.

Comment: @Ripley511 I post a little bit more of my script on the main message

Comment: You do realize that `this.http.get` is an http call as I've said in my first comment right?

Comment: @Dellirium ReflexPage {modalCtrl: ModalController, http: Http, items: Array[0]} and when i expand it : items:Array[8]

Comment: @AlvinFREY so your items is an empty array, not the one you posted in the shot, which means the loop works, you are just looping through an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will iterate on the array itself and return all items in it as objects in the inline function.

```
this.items.forEach( function (item)
{
 item.xxx=11;
} );
```

Comment: When I started to edit the answer in my mobile phone,there were no posts yet, so did not know someone is writing the same.

Comment: @torazaburo sry..the comment was directed at Miro

Comment: I would just let him try it ;) peace

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.http.get("assets/data/" + elementData + "Reflex.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

    Array.prototype.push.apply(itemsArray, data);

  });
```

This call is the problem.It is *asynchronous*.

The for loop will not wait for the response to push data into `itemArray`.
A rough way to get the array is:

```
      this.http.get("assets/data/" + elementData + "Reflex.json").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

        Array.prototype.push.apply(this.items, data);//make sure this.items is set to empty previous to call

      });
```